# CSS collapse list of categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have the following html toggles collapse/uncollapse when clicking "Categories" with only CSS.

I can't change the Html but I can add CSS.

```
<div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_meta prdctfltr_text prdctfltr_single" data-filter="mta_vendor_2_10" data-limit="0">
    <input name="mta_vendor_2_10" type="hidden">
    <span class="prdctfltr_regular_title">Categories<i class="prdctfltr-down"></i></span>

    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll" style="max-height:;">
        <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
            <label class="prdctfltr_ft_none"><input type="checkbox" value=""><span>none</span></label>
            <label class="prdctfltr_ft_cat1"><span><input type="checkbox" value="cat1"><span>Category 1</span></span></label>
            <label class="prdctfltr_ft_cat2"><span><input type="checkbox" value="cat2"><span>Category 2</span></span></label>
            <label class="prdctfltr_ft_cat3"><span><input type="checkbox" value="cat3"><span>Category 3</span></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include your css also, better make an example on jsfiddle

Comment: Use CSS Animation

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** :-)

With `:focus` pseudo class.

```
<div class="target" tabindex="0">Click me</div>
<div class="menu">I am menu</div>

.target + .menu {
  display: block
}

.target:focus + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Demo:

```css
  .target + .menu {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .target:focus + .menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="target" tabindex="0">Click me</div>
    <div class="menu">I <br>am<br> menu</div>
```

Comment: I tried: 

.prdctfltr_regular_title + .prdctfltr_add_scroll {
    display: none;
}

.prdctfltr_regular_title:focus + .prdctfltr_add_scroll {
    display: block;
}

but didn't work.

Comment: thank you, pretty creative way!, still not a `click` effect, but very close.

Comment: "please note that he ***can't change the HTML***. So your option is invalid..." - [TVA van Hesteren](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7114793/tva-van-hesteren)

Answer (score 1):

**No**,

there is no 'click' event in pure CSS ***(since you can't change your HTML)***. You could do it with hover, but that will obviously only work on hovering.

If you can add some javascript, you can add a class on click and use that class for the CSS-styling.